# Alternative of document object in node

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on a react component to copy text on clipboard. I am using `document.execCommand('copy')` for it, which is working fine for browsers. However it may not found **"document" object** in other environment and will break there ie. node.

Is there any alternative I can use to make it work for cross platform?

Comment: in other environments means what exactly?Is there no node setup?

Comment: Other environments could be if we are trying to render node at server side, or testing application without browser

Answer (score 2):

[`jsdom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) is widely used in Node.js applications to provide support for *some* client-side features, primarily DOM. `document.execCommand` is [not among them](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1539).

In order for `document.execCommand('copy')` to not cause an error during SSR, client-side features in use can be stubbed in Node:

```
global.document = {
  execCommand() {}
};
```

An alternative approach is to detect Node.js environment, e.g. with [`detect-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-node). Either with in-place conditions:

```
if (isNode)
  document.execCommand('copy');
```

Or by using loosely coupled components and IoC/DI containers. Redux store or React context can act as a container which platform-dependent components can be read from.

For instance, with [React 16.3 context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

```
const ClipboardComponent = (props) => /* default implementation */;

export const PlatformContainer = React.createContext({
  ClipboardComponent,
});
```

The component is retrieved from the context where it's used:

```
<PlatformContainer.Consumer>{({ ClipboardComponent }) => 
  <ClipboardComponent/>
}</PlatformContainer.Consumer>
```

It's rendered with default implementation on client side:

```
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And no-op implementation can be provided in entry point on server side:

```
renderToString(
  <PlatformContext.Provider value={ { ClipboardComponent: () => null } }>
    <App />
  </PlatformContext.Provider>
);
```